# Префікси і прийменники од- і від-

Tags: вибір-слова, прийменники, префікс

<sub>Це по сутї перествір запита [***одразу** чи **відразу***](/q/6849/585), котрий, на превеликий жаль, цїлком підпадає під *opinion-base*, тобто основане на думках, а не на витягах чи фактах, але  ніхто ся не втручаїть. Менї сумно, бо тема цїкава або варта належної уваги. Гинших подібних запитів тут немає або не знайшов.</sub>

- Приросток чи -іменник *од-* це архаїзм, полонізм, ще який-сь *-ізм* чи що-сь таки инше?
- Якщо останнє, то які особївостї вжитку: гісторичні, чинні і за стандардом?

<sub>Оскільки самовідповідь, дозволю собі не розписувати запит думками чи ланками на блоґи чи форуми.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>За основу беру статтю [*Історія і нормативний статус прийменника / префікса **од‑** в українській мові нового часу*](//journals.pan.pl/dlibra/publication/143220/edition/125858) ([Людмила Дика](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ASPB/0030444), [Марія Шведова](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ASUA/0109461)). За що їм окрема подяка. Особисто раджу почитати (всього, якщо не менше 22 сторінок), бо праця справдї добра, а витяги думок декотрих осіб — просто показові і по своєму прекрасні в тий чи гинший спосіб, така собі комедія.</sub>

## Гісторія

> <sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>
>
> [**ВІД**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4#3163) (прийменник)
>
> усі форми з псл. *otъ*, форми з **-д** виникли за аналогією до *над*, *під* (*под*), *пе́ред*;

---

Додаткові тези чи розлогіше з працї [*Історична фонологія української мови*](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001641) ([Юрій Шевельов](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)).

Форма з **-д** спершу була запроваджена перед сонорними і голосними.

В північноукраїнському наріччї форму **од** памятки фіксують з середини ⅩⅤ ст. (бл. 1450 р.), форми з **від‑** — з початку ⅩⅥ ст. (бл. 1500 р.).

Форма **від** виникла на територіях, охоплених [протезою](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0): протетичний **в** перед **о**:

> це в ґрунті речі наддністрянське та надсянське говіркове явище, що заторкує також Підляшшя, західну частину Поділля й чималі шматки буковинсько‑покутської, східнобойківської та східнолемківської діалектних зон.

Від себе також зазначу, що **ъ** в **одъ** може виринати як **о**, що згодом стає і як **і**, тому можемо мати також **одо-**, **оді-**, **віді-** ітп.

## Ґеоґрафія

<sub>Можна клацнути на картинку, аби відкрити окремо і там маштабувати.</sub>

<sup>[*Атлас української мови*, т. 1](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0002501), к. 269</sup>
[image]

<sup>[*Атлас української мови*, т. 2](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0002502), к. 251</sup>
[image]

<sup>[*Атлас української мови*, т. 3](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0002502), к. 128</sup>
[image]

Тобто словами:

- **од‑**/**від‑** паралельно співіснують лише на теренах новоствореного південно‑східного наріччя,
- в південно‑західних, за винятком північних районів волинського говору і карпатських говірок, — **від**,
- в північних — **од**.

Як підкреслив [Леонід Булаховський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%90%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) в працї [*Питання походження української мови*](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009997):

> Прийменник‑префікс, що відповідає колишньому **от**(**ъ**), виступає в варіантах **од** (не під наголосом) і **від**: в одних південно‑східних говірках — із перевагою другого; в інших (головним чином — близьких до північного наріччя) — першого. Є й говірки, де правило становить або **від**, або **од** (не під наголосом).

Тому твердження на зразок *так [через **од**] кажуть лише в селах на Галичині, які зазнали сильної полонізації* від декотрих ві згаданому запитї є абсолютно безпідставними і помилковими.

## Нормалізація

<sub>*Насамперед менї цїкавять особївостї вжитку, тобто правила. Тому статістіка винесена в окремий параґраф, де добра частина — пропущена. Повністю буде пропущені приклади класиків чи просто письменників.*</sub>

Чи не перша спроба нормалізації постала десь під час мовної дискусії 1906–13 рр.

Основні думки:

- Радікальні, лише:

  - **од** ([Нечуй-Левицький](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)),
  - **від**, одна з причин — вирізнитися ся з гинших словянських мов, насамперед польської і московської.
- Як [евфонію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F) ([Михайло Пачовський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [Василь Сімович](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)), тобто писати **від-** після голосних. Схоже на ідею фікс і знов схожїсть з декотрими префіксами, але вже з гишими.
- Рівноправні; можливі додаткові зауваги, що:

  - **від** як головна чи переважна ([Олекса Синявський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)).

Цїкаво, що тут нічого не сказано про згаданого ранїше наголоса. Схоже, це лишили як особливість певному діялекту або просто пропустили.

[Борис Грінченко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) був не проти другої думки, однак в словницї використав першу — **від-** є основним суфіксом, лише геть декотрі слова з **од-** отримали окрему статтю, а ті що нї, а таких чимало — записані в тій самій формі ві витягах, але в статтях під **від-**, нп.:

> [**Ві́дкуп**](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF&scope=all&dicts=12&highlight=on), -пу, м.
>
> Откупъ. *Не раз із селами й церкви ім на **одкуп** **оддавали***. К. ЧР. 10.

Десь подібна поведінка була від укладача як [Агатангел Кримський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), і така практіка поширила ся на гинші майбутнї словники без змін чи з декотрими. Схоже, це один з чинників панування форми **від-**.

Щодо чинного — [2019 року](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=37) — правописа, то тут було повністю усунено **од-**:

> § 31.
>
> 2. У префіксах **без-**, **від-**, **між-**, **над-**, **об-**, **перед-**, **під-**, **понад-**, **роз-**, **через-** кінцевий дзвінкий приголосний перед наступним глухим приголосним не змінюємо…

Для порівняння [попередній](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par21p2):

> § 21.
>
> 2. У всіх префіксах — **без-**, **від-** (**од-**), **між-**, **над-**, **об-**, **під-**, **перед-**, **понад-**, **пред-**, **роз-**, **через-** — кінцевий дзвінкий приголосний перед глухими не змінюється…

### Статістіка

<sub>*Лише загальна. Пропущено реґійональні, авторські ітд. Також треба мати на увазї, що статістіка чутлива від різних чинників, тому не є 100 % доводом, а радше тенденцією чи ілустраційою.*</sub>

<sup>Розподіл вживань варіантів в [корпусі] [ҐРАК](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)-12 за роками.</sup>
[image]

Леґенда:

- *оранжеве*: **од**/**од-**;
- *синє*: **від**/**від-**.

Форма *од-* зазвичай волостива церковнословянізмам, наприклад *одкровення* має вжиток тільки такий. А також переважає при чистому, тобто без префікса **з-**, корню *віт*, тобто *одвіт*, *одвітити* ітп.

### Гіперкорекція

Якщо опустити відому, навіть дещо меметичну, [гіперкорекцію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) як [*от кутір*](/q/778/585), то можна зазначити про *одвертий* → *відвертий*, де насправді приросток **о** і корінь *двер*, що від *твір*/*твор* як в *о-твор-ити*.

## Короткий підсумок

Обі форми є питомо українськими, однак певні форми притамані певних реґійонам, лише один мав парабіжний вжив, котрий, схоже, залежав від наголосу. Точно не можа вважати галицьким (декотрі ставять *галицьке = польське* через невиховану необізнаність), бо там якраз переважало і переважає форма **від-**.

Особївостї вжитку зумовєні таким чином:

- (гісторично) реґійонально лише одна певна форма, лише в одному дві зі залежністю від наголоса,
- (чинним стандардом) начебто лише **від**,
- (чинно, узусно) рівноправні, але **від** панує; правил як таких — немає.

Можна окремо зазначити, що спроба в евфонію — не пройдена часом.